# mypy error:Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "str")

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I have this very simple function:

```
import datetime

def create_url(check_in: datetime.date) -> str:
"""take date such as '2018-06-05' and transform to format '06%2F05%2F2018'"""
    _check_in = check_in.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    _check_in = _check_in.split("-")
    _check_in = _check_in[1] + "%2F" + _check_in[2] + "%2F" + _check_in[0]

    return f"https://www.website.com/?arrival={_check_in}"
```

mypy throws the following error:
`error:Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[str]", variable has type "str")` for line 6 `_check_in = _check_in.split("-")`.
I've tried renaming `_check_in`on line 6 but that makes no difference. This function works fine.

Is this the expected behavior? How do I fix the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Btw your code is missing an extra `"` which is causing your code block to format like a docstring

Comment: Thanks - that's now corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first line `_check_in = check_in.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`, `_check_in` is a string (or `str` as mypy like to think), then in `_check_in = _check_in.split("-")` `_check_in` becomes a list of string (`List[str]`), since mypy already think this should be a `str`, it will complain (or rather warn you about it as it's not a particularly nice practice).

As for how you should fix it, just rename the variable appropriately, or you can do `_check_in = _check_in.split("-")  # type: List[str]` (and also `_check_in = _check_in[1] + "%2F" + _check_in[2] + "%2F" + _check_in[0]  # type: str` the line below) if you are dead set on using `_check_in` as the variable name.

## EDIT

Maybe you want to do this instead

```
import datetime

def create_url(check_in: datetime.datetime) -> str:
    return "https://www.website.com/?arrival={0}".format(
        check_in.strftime('%d%%2F%m%%2F%Y'),
    )
```

Comment: That actually makes mypy go "error:Name '_check_in' already defined". mypy is silent if I use a different name for check_in on each line. It just seems very unpythonic to use four names for check_in in such a simple function.

Comment: Edited my answer for a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work ok for me? This is my implementation of your code

```
import datetime

def create_url(check_in):
    """take date such as '2018-06-05' and transform to format '06%2F05%2F2018'"""
    _check_in = check_in.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    _check_in = _check_in.split("-")
    _check_in = _check_in[1] + "%2F" + _check_in[2] + "%2F" + _check_in[0]

    return "https://www.website.com/?arrival={0}".format(_check_in)

today = datetime.date.today()
print(create_url(today))

>>> https://www.website.com/?arrival=05%2F28%2F2018
```

Comment: It works fine as also stated in the question. The issue is why mypy throws an error.

Comment: The reason your example code doesn't cause mypy to error is because the `check_in` argument isn't typed.  Mypy assigns the type of `Any` to `check_in`, which results in `_check_in` being assigned a type of `Any` as well.